# gdb : cannot execute: Undefined error: 0

Tags: gdb, osx-yosemite

I've installed gdb as per the following steps:

- `brew install homebrew/dupes/gdb`
- follow instructions exactly as per http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin

However when I try `run` inside gdb, I get:

```
...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/snowch/tmp/myc/main 
/bin/bash: /Users/snowch/tmp/myc/main: Permission denied
/bin/bash: line 0: exec: /Users/snowch/tmp/myc/main: cannot execute: Undefined error: 0
During startup program exited with code 126.
```

I've tried reinstalling gdb and creating and signing with a new certificate.   Still no joy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't this look like a problem with the application you're trying to debug? Perhaps the "Permission denied" is relevant?

Comment: I made some small changes to the file, recompiled and it works now!  Many thanks @DrWatson